# npm use local modules

Tags: node.js, npm, babeljs, node-modules

I've just installed the `babel-cli` module locally to my project but when I run `babel test.js` in the terminal it outputs that the `*command babel is uknown*`.

What I figured out is that `npm` is trying to find the module in my globally installed modules instead of my project modules, how can I fix it?

Sorry for the silly question but I'm not finding a solution.

Answer (score 1):

You can either

1. Use the babel installed in you project - `node_modules/.bin/babel test.js`
2. Add a [script](https://docs.npmjs.com/files/package.json#scripts) in your `package.json` and run it via npm - `npm run <script_name>`. `npm` will use the version of babel installed in your project

Answer (score 0):

When you run babel. It looks for global npm directory and can't find it there.

**2 ways but one is redundant.**

- You can link your local path to global npm directory which is
  redundant and wont work for the next project. Don't never do this.
- Or install it globally. That how npm works for now.

There is a discussion on that. And here is a good article. http://www.joezimjs.com/javascript/no-more-global-npm-packages/